# Material-UI Sizing Confusion

Tags: material-ui, theming, sizing

In the [sizing](https://material-ui.com/system/sizing/#sizing) documentation, it says "Easily make an element as wide or as tall (relative to its parent) with the width and height utilities.".

What I realize is that almost all the examples in system section of documentation, examples mostly related to Box component. I tried some of the tricks from there on Button element. And expectedly nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for those who is new on material (actually UI) this is a bit tricky. first, they use Box because as per [box documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/box/) they said box generated using material styled (not the styled-components) "The Box component packages all the [style functions](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#all-inclusive) that are exposed in @material-ui/system. It's created using the styled() function of @material-ui/core/styles."

So, I went to the github and material core repository to understand how to do that.

```
export const styleFunction = css(
  compose(
    borders,
    display,
    flexbox,
    grid,
    positions,
    palette,
    shadows,
    sizing,
    spacing,
    typography,
  ),
);
```

css and compose are also exported from `@material-ui/system`

then at the end of the file;

```
const Box = styled(BoxRoot, { shouldForwardProp }, { muiName: 'MuiBox' })(styleFunction);

export default Box;
```

The `styled` used here is from an `experimentalStyled` package (an internal package) but that does not matter. Cuz, Material guys exporting a styled function/hook for our use.

`import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";`

I tried this styled function for Button component.

```
const CustomButton = styled(Button)(sizing);
```

adn yes it worked. I am now able to apply magical styling skills defined in the **system**  section of material UI.

For those who wants to use this instead of other methods. I pushed an npm package too.

[material-ui-styled-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-styled-hook)